how to remove such errors to have a successful deployment
6:43:51 PM: npm error syscall open
6:43:51 PM: npm error path /opt/build/repo/package.json
6:43:51 PM: npm error errno -2
6:43:51 PM: npm error enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/package.json'
6:43:51 PM: npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
6:43:51 PM: npm error enoent
6:43:51 PM: npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2024-06-24T13_13_51_476Z-debug-0.log
6:43:51 PM: ​
6:43:51 PM: "build.command" failed                                        
6:43:51 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:43:51 PM: ​
6:43:51 PM:   Error message
6:43:51 PM:   Command failed with exit code 254: CI= npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-254)
6:43:51 PM: ​
6:43:51 PM:   Error location
6:43:51 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
6:43:51 PM:   CI= npm run build
6:43:51 PM: ​
6:43:51 PM:   Resolved config
6:43:51 PM:   build:
6:43:51 PM:     command: CI= npm run build
6:43:51 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
6:43:51 PM:     environment:
6:43:51 PM:       - CI
6:43:51 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo
6:43:51 PM:     publishOrigin: default
6:43:51 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
6:43:51 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
6:43:52 PM: Finished processing build request in 11.429s


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

package.json file, which is essential for running npm install and npm run build, is missing.
I think you are deploying to Netlify by using your git, and probably, you are missing your package.json file.
Please try to deploy it manually.
Just build first in React itself:


npm run build



Then take your build folder manually and send it to netlify. It will be deployed successfully.
If want only deploy with github, please make sure that you are not missing package.json file in your repository, because it is important. Check your git .gitignore file before pushing into github. package.json file in your json, please remove it from your gitignore.
Hope this will help!

thank you bro... the file uploaded successfully but only the homepage is loading properly, rest of the functionalities are not working properly. Please guide

Ensure that your React app's routing is properly configured. Otherwise, it will not work as expected! Try to check it. I cannot say what is exactly happening untill seeing your code! If you want just text me from telegram @fazliddin_fayziev.  I will explain your problem by using video chat. Do not worry, it is free :) Happy to help!
